# Gave up waiting for root device - dropping to a shell

Tags: boot

While booting into Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, I get the following message:

```
Gave up waiting for root device.  Common problems:

- Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
- Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
- Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
- Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev) 

ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/177ca7ce-7671-49d6-b97e-32494cfe4fdf does not exist.
Dropping to a shell!
BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash) 
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands

(initramfs) _
```

If I type "exit" then press enter, I get the splash screen and can log-in.

If I search for the uuid it appears to be there; so, I am not sure why I am ALERTed that is doesn't exist.

```
[by-uuid] ls -l 
[ 4:01PM] total 0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 20 15:28 07107cba-29bb-485a-a3c8-be14411f0f34 -> ../../sda6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 20 15:28 1437-E09A -> ../../sda2 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 20 15:28 177ca7ce-7671-49d6-b97e-32494cfe4fdf -> ../../sda5 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 20 15:28 407836FB7836EF72 -> ../../sda1 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 20 15:28 B2C63A9AC63A5EB3 -> ../../sda4
```

I have run Boot-repair, which did nothing ​to help the problem but did give me the following link http://paste.ubuntu.com/24910706/

This is a dual-boot system with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Is Ubuntu on sda5?

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu is on sda5.

Answer (score 1):

From terminal:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

From gedit add  `rootdelay=15` inside quotation marks in the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` to make

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rootdelay=15"
```

Save and close.

From terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

And reboot. Repeat the process, adding 15 to rootdelay until the problem is resolved. For me 75 did the trick.

Comment: Is there a better answer? This saves me from having to type "exit" but it means I am staring at a black screen for 75 secs.